# Smooth CSS slide down animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm tryin to get a smooth slide down animation by adding a class to a div with an click event.

It kinda "jumps" really fast right when the animation starts and then evens out, but it look really janky and I'm not sure why.

It's currently using the `max-height` method to add a height to the div to "open" and then when it's clicked again, it toggles a class which has `max-height:0`.

Seems fine if you have a bunch of elements in the hidden div that is supposed to slide down, but if you only have one or two the slide down animation is pretty jumpy. Wondering if I need to use `transform:translateY` instead or not?

Here's a link to an example (Codepen):
https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/ZrxNrj/

```js
var premiumOptions = $(".package-header");
$(premiumOptions).click(handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  console.log("clicked");
  var description = $(this)
    .parent()
    .find(".description");
  if ($(description).length) {
    $(description).toggleClass("open closed");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.package-item {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.closed {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  will-change: transform;
}

.open {
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="package-item line">
  <div class="flex-row package-header">
    <h3>Click This</h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="description closed">
    <li>This is the thing that needs to show smoothly</li>
    <li>This is the thing that needs to show smoothly</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears to have everything to do with removing the padding in `.closed`, if you don't remove the padding it is seamless. Seems the animation and padding remove fire at different times. I am unsure how to fix this though.

Comment: Nevermind, I agree with @animake changing the max-height looks correct.

Comment: I think your animation were too fast for the **.description** because the height of it were too small. Try lowering the animation to 1s and apply it to **.description** `transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`. You don't need to apply the animation to **.closed** and **.open** but you need to apply the animation to the element that will have transition, which is in this case is **.description**.

Comment: I see you're using jQuery. Why not just use jQuery.animate()?

Comment: You could use `.slideToggle('slow')` instead of `toggleClass`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `max-height: 1000px;` is causing an issue with the transition, I tried low values, It looked smooth. Try considering the `max-height` value in the .open css.

```js
var premiumOptions = $(".package-header");
$(premiumOptions).click(handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  console.log("clicked");
  var description = $(this)
    .parent()
    .find(".description");
  if ($(description).length) {
    $(description).toggleClass("open closed");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.package-item {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.closed {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  will-change: transform;
}

.open {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="package-item line">
  <div class="flex-row package-header">
    <h3>Click This</h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="description closed">
    <li>This is the thing that needs to show smoothly</li>
    <li>This is the thing that needs to show smoothly</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah moving the transition into the description class and then lowering the max height seems to iron that out a bit. I might even go as far to get the height of the description and then pass that in as the max-height with a click event to future proof any additional content.